# Насколько актуально сегодня писать под j2me?

Tags: j2me, java

Нужно написать программу для телефона: сначала планирую писать для wp7, потом портирую под Android, дальше видно будет. Есть ли смысл писать под стандартную j2me? В чём преимущества и недостатки данной платформы? В инете пошарил - вся информация очень старая и складывается впечатление что эта платформа умирает

Comment: Чисто под j2me - фиг знает, но посмотри в сторону кроссплатформенных фреймворков (Marmelade, MonoTouch, Uniti3D и т.п.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как старый, старый девелопер под J2ME внесу свои 5 копеек.

1. J2ME технология умирающая
2. Причин смерти много, одной из них является излишне строгая модель безопасности. Говоря проще для того, чтобы написать приложение которое делает более-менее вменяемое действие: типа выйти в сеть, отправить СМС, создать блютус соединение - необходимо покупать сертификат и что самое противное, даже это не гарантирует от того, что все будет работать. В общем тема большая, обширная, копий сломано немало. Хорошо написано об этом [здесь](http://javablog.co.uk/2007/08/09/how-midlet-signing-is-killing-j2me/) - статья старая, написана еще в 2007 году - тогда наверное еще что-то можно было изменить, сейчас уже поздно.
3. Еще одной проблемой J2ME является проблема монетизации приложений. Нормальных AppStore как у Android и Apple здесь нет. Был у Nokia Ovi и то накрылся. Каждый выкручивается как может. Рекламная модель монетизации также работает из рук вон плохо (опять же по причине секьюрности).
4. На текущий момент J2ME востребован в развивающихся странах. У меня есть приложение с 300 тыс. закачек - так вот 80% закачек это Индия, Малайзия, Китай, Индонезия, Нигерия и проч. - а в этих странах с бабками туго :)

В общем все девелоперы уже давно перешли под Android и iPhone. Я тоже уже пару лет не брал в руки шашку J2ME и еще года 4 назад начал пересаживаться на Android. Ну разве что полгода назад по слезным просьбам трудящихся Ирана перевел одно свое приложение на фарси.

Answer (score 1):

Прелесть в том, что java-приложения сейчас поддерживаются почти всеми телефонами (не говоря уже о смартфонах). К  тому же, их (обычных телефонов) по статистике больше, чем "умных" - т.е. потенциальных пользователей больше.

Comment: Из ваших слов следует, что это единственные преимущества. Но это не главное, меня интересует, есть ли там библиотеки для работы с gps? Я вот что-то не могу найти информацию по этой теме. И если есть, то насколько хорошо имплементированы?

Comment: Доля простых устройств, если не ошибаюсь, постепенно падает, а доля остальных - растёт. При этом, все умные устройства не поддерживают j2me.

Comment: поясните "все умные устройства не поддерживают j2me".